# Hyperlink in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this in MVC3 Razor.. I want to make this a hyperlink..so users can click on it. Right now it just prints the text of the URL in the view.. thanks for your help.

```
   <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WebLink)
    </td>
```

Thanks to Richard, heres the solution..

```
  @{
       var link = @item.WebLink;
       if (link != null)
       {
           if (!link.StartsWith("http://"))
            { 
               link = "http://"+link;
            }
       }
     }

        <a href="@link">@item.WebLink</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should try:

```
<a href="@item.WebLink">@item.WebLink</a>
```

OK from you comment you will need this:

```
@{
   var link = @item.WebLink;
   if (!link.StartsWith("http://")) { link = "http://"+link; }
}

<a href="@link">@item.WebLink</a>
```

Comment: But the click is not taking me to the google URL.. its actually taking me to http://localhost:2323/Controller/ActionName/www.google.com..   anything I am missing?

Comment: Ok fixed now for the http issue

Comment: You are missing the paranthesis..  I modified a little bit.. this works best. Thank you for showing me the right way to do this..I edited the original post also.. 
         @{
           var link = @item.WebLink;
           if (link != null)
           {
               if (!link.StartsWith("http://"))
                { 
                   link = "http://"+link;
                }
           }
         }

            <a href="@link">@item.WebLink</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
<td><a href="@item.WebLink">@item.WebLink</a></td>
```

Assuming item is the variable name within your for loop.

Comment: But the click is not taking me to the google URL.. its actually taking me to localhost:2323/Controller/ActionName/www.google.com.. anything I am missing? – ZVenue

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@{
    string site = "www.google.com";
}

<a href="http://@site"> Go to the site @site </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

conver it into

simple html

```
<a href="@item.WebLink">Linkname</a>
```

if you want it in razor

```
@html.actionlink("@item.WebLink","actionname","controllername")
```

i dont knw in which format ur link will come but
if it is in home/index jst split it using split("/") and use it in razor